# Unallocated disk space

Tags: gparted

I had a dual boot-able system with Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian. I wanted to remove debian so I opened GParted and deleted the partition with Debian. After doing so I thought I could simply resize the Ubuntu partition but I am not able. Now I am left with partitions:

1) /dev/sda1 (ext4)

2) /dev/sda2 Extended >unallocated

3) /dev/sda5Linux-swap

Sorry can't attach a picture.

I also ran GParted from a live CD but had the same problems.

All I really want is Ubuntu on one partition and of course the linux swap.

Does anyone have a way to fix my situation I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make all your changes one step at a time. First of course you have to be running from a live CD with all the partitions unmounted, including swap. You can unmount them from gparted if need be.

1. Resize the extended partition (/dev/sda2) , free space in front , adjacent to /dev/sda1
2. Apply changes.
3. Resize /dev/sda1
4. Apply changes.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately,I am unable to unmount either from the GParted or Disk Utility apps when running from the live cd.

Comment: When running live, what can you not unmount ? `sudo swapoff -a` will do swap. look closer at the menu I gparted, unmount should be an option.

Comment: If I select either of the partitions in GParted live, the unmount is not highlighted.

Comment: Here is a snapshot of terminal listing partitions:   http://www.pasteall.org/pic/29411

Comment: Here is a screenshot of GParted: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/29412

Comment: select a partition , right click to show the menu in my screen shot. Alternately, `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and `sudo swapoff -a`

Comment: Okay. I was able to unmount partitions with the command you gave me then follow your instructions. Everything running and working fine. Thank you very much. Take care.

Comment: If you have a moment, I have one more question. Now that I have re-sized my drive and only have Ubuntu 12.04 beta installed on this computer, when I boot up, the option to boot the removed Debian OS is still present. Is there a way to update and remove this?

Comment: Try "sudo update-grub" in Ubuntu. If this does not answer your question, create a new one, since further comments will be buried down and will likely not be read. Also, please update and/or accept the answers that were useful to you. Thank you !